# iOS First launch trouble

Tags: ios

I have 3 view controllers with the `NSUserDefault` bool values for detecting first launch and calling the tutorial func. But, in one of view controllers, it doesn't work as it should:

I have a custom animated segue with VCs

```
main vc -> img vc
img vc exit -> main vc

main vc -> sett vc
sett vc exit -> main vc
```

I tried to write `println` in the `viewDidLoad` in main vc and I find out that the `viewDidLoad` method works only when the app opens, all other time when I come back to main vc it doesn't work. (in two other vcs it works every time when I segue to them)

I have no idea how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand. I try an answer here, and if it doesn't satisfy your needs, please provide more code.

I believe you mix up a `didLoad` and a `didAppear` delegate method.
If you want to trigger code every time a view will be shown to the user, use the `viewDidAppear` delegate-method.

`viewDidLoad` is called only once, when the view is loaded to memory. If you use a navigationcontroller and segue back to the view (which is already loaded in memory), viewDidLoad will NOT be called again. But `viewDidAppear` will